# Show that if $A ⊆ B$, then $C - B ⊆ C - A$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

Show that if $A ⊆ B$,
$C - B ⊆ C - A$

I've tried doing this by introducing an element $x$ that is in both $A$ and $B$ and an element $y$ that is in $B$ and $C$ but I can't seem to find a proof which makes sense.

Comment: Assume that $x \in C \setminus B$. Then $x \in C$ and $x \notin B$. But $A \subseteq B$ and thus $x \notin A$.

Comment: Just to put this into english, just show that all elements $x \in C - B$ are elements in $C - A$. Set $y \in C - A$.  Show all the conditions on $x$. Show all the conditions on $y$. Show that $x$ satisfies being a $y$

Answer (score 2):

Suppose Otherwise $C - B \nsubseteq C-A\implies \exists x \in C-B, x \notin C-A\implies x \notin B, x \in A\implies A \nsubseteq B$, contradiction. Thus the statement must be true.

Answer (score 2):

$A \subset B$:

Let $z \in C-B$ , then

$z \in C$ and $x \not \in B$.

$x \not \in B$ implies $x \not \in A$, since $A \subset B$.

Hence $z \in C$ and $x \not \in A$, i .e.

$z \in C -A$.

Answer (score 1):

We have to show $C-B\subseteq C-A$. 
Where $A,B\subseteq C$ and $A\subseteq B$.

Let $x\in C-B$. Then $x\in C$ and $x\notin B$ by the defintion of the difference of sets. Since $A\subseteq B$ it is $x\notin A$.
Suppose $x\in A$ then $A\subseteq B$ is wrong, since there is an element $x\in A$ with $x\notin B$. By the definition of subsets.

Thus $x\in C$ and $x\notin A$, which means $x\in C-A$. 
And we showed $C-B\subseteq C-A$.